# Angular : How to show md-error which is inside md-input-container from code without considering Validators inside the attached formcontrol?

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have an input field

```
<md-input-container class="margin-top-little">
    <input mdInput placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onBlur()" name="{{name}}" [formControl]="validator"
    (change)="onChange()" (focus)="onfocus()">
    <md-error *ngIf="validator.hasError('minlength') || validator.hasError('maxlength') ||  validator.hasError('allowed_values') || service_error_type">
        Please enter a valid {{placeholder}}
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="validator.hasError('required') || service_error_missing">
        {{placeholder}} is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

I want to show the 2nd `md-error` with the help of an event or any flag but not the value inside the ngModel .

How to do this ?

Main motive is to map field level errors coming from services to the respective fields .

Comment: You may want to have a look at custom error matchers https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher

Answer (score 0):

The `md-error` is created and destroyed by the `*ngIf` structural directive. If you want to show or hide an `<md-error></md-error>` or any `<> </>` HTML element, you would want to put your condition in the *ngIF statement (e.g. `*ngIf = " event === true "`)

```
<md-error *ngIf="validator.hasError('required') || service_error_missing">
</md-error>
```

to

```
<md-error *ngIf="condition">
</md-error>
```

or more generally:

```
<html-element-tag *ngIf="condition"></html-element-tag>
```

where `condition` is a function, variable, or statement which returns (or equates) to either "true" or "false"